# How to use fallback values for `display` property in CSS?

Tags: css, fallback

I want to use `display: inline-table` and `display: table-cell`, but it doesn't work on old browsers like IE7, so I want a `display: inline-block` fallback.

According to http://afshinm.name/css-fallback-properties-better-cross-browser-compatibility/, with `color` property it's possible to use

```css
.me {
    color: #ccc;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Then, I tried

```css
#wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    display: inline-table;
}

#wrapper > .child {
    display: inline-block;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

but IE7 tries to use `display: inline-table`, `display: table-cell` instead of `display: inline-block`, even if they don't work.

**Notes**

- I don't want to use JS nor another stylesheet inside conditional comments to achieve that
- I want it to be valid CSS

Comment: A valid CSS approach would likely only be possible with conditional comments.

Comment: Gracefully degrade for IE7

Comment: Just a suggestion I haven't tried, would the `!important` tag help? I know putting `cursor: hand; cursor: pointer !important;` is done pretty often...

Comment: AFAIK, in IE7 display:inline-block works only for initially inline elements like spans. So the problem might be not in that browsers try to use the non-supported value, but in that they don't support the fallback either and end up using default display:block. Inline-block can be emulated in IE7- by using display:inline along with zoom:1 (or any other property that enables hasLayout).

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn Oh, I thought I had said it but I forgot. In my case that's not a problem because the elements are inline by default, so `inline-block` should work. The problem is that, since `inline-table` nor `table-cell` aren't supported, elements behave `inline`

Comment: @Tyblitz I have tried `#wrapper{ display: inline-table !important;  display: inline-block; }` but I have the same problem: IE7 tries to use `inline-table !important` but it can't, so `#wrapper` becomes `inline` instead of `inline-block`

Comment: This may be a very stupid question, but are you actually testing in IE7? When I test with IE9 in IE7 mode, I can duplicate your problem (span becomes inline-table, and the browser can't display it). However, IE9 in IE7 mode is NOT IE7, so this could be one of those incompatibilities. It could be that the CSS parser in IE9 does not treat `inline-table` as an error, although the display engine does.

Comment: @Oriol, that's strange; given that when a browser doesn't recognize a property it normally skips it. I am unfortunately unable to help you further; IE 7 is indeed not IE9+ in IE7 mode; you might want to try browsershots.org or search for IETester...

Comment: @MrLister, Tyblitz I have tried it on IE8 in IE7 mode and IETester IE7 mode. And other times IE8 in IE7 mode didn't behave like IE7, IETester did. But I will try browsershots.org just in case

Comment: @Tyblitz I have tried browsershots.org and on IE7 the behavior is like `inline` instead of `inline-block`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm at a loss then =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing you're just looking for a fallback solution for IE7, this can be done.

Add a new rule which start with `*:first-child+html` and only IE7 will recognise it.

So in your case add

```
*:first-child+html #wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}

*:first-child+html #wrapper > .child {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Why `*:first-child+html`? Well, that translates as an html element that is a following sibling of another element that is the first child of of their common parent. While it possible to create such DOMs in invalid `application/xhtml+xml`-served XHTML and via JavaScript, in normal HTML the HTML parser rules mean that simply never happens.

But IE7 has a bug, where it matches the `*:first-child` against the DOCTYPE node, which since that node is a preceding sibling node of the html element, the rule applies.

IE6 did not support `:first-child`, IE8 and later do not match `*` against the DOCTYPE node.

Adding `*:first-child+html` to the same selector has the additional benefit of increasing the specificity of the selector, so it will always take precedence in IE7.

The additional rules are entirely valid CSS.

You can see it in action at http://alohci.net/static/ie7cssfallback.htm