# How to align buttons (in different forms) horizontally in IE7

Tags: html, css, button, internet-explorer-7

I have the following bit of code which comprises of 3 buttons:

```
<div id="button-panel">
    <form action="../edit/" method="GET">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $record->id; ?>" />
     <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
    </form>

    <form action="" method="POST">
     <input  type="submit" name="cancel_btn" value="Cancel" />
    </form> 

  <input type="button" id="boh-url-gen" value="Generate URL" onClick="generateURL();" />                    
</div>  <!-- button-panel -->
```

Despite my efforts the buttons align vertically in IE7. Currently I have the following CSS applied:

```
#button-panel *{display:inline-block;}
```

However, it fails to work for IE7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply because `display:inline-block` isn't fully supported by IE7. [**Reference here.**](http://caniuse.com/inline-block)

If you want full support, just float the elements.

```
#button-panel {
    float:left; /* right */
}
```

Note, floating an element takes it out of the flow, so you might need to add something like `overflow:auto` to the parent - assuming the content is collapsing because a fixed `height`/`width` isn't set.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 doesn't support `display:inline-block` on elements which are `block` be default.

Instead, `display:inline` makes them behave like `inline-block` (IE7 is so weird)

So you can use conditional comments to create a stylesheet for IE7, or IE7 CSS hacks, with `display:inline`. For example:

```
*:first-child+html #button-panel { /* IE7 hack which is valid CSS */
    display: inline;
}
```

(IE7 hack from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19073503/1529630) by [Alohci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42585/alohci))

Comment: Why would `display:inline` work..? It doesn't have the same characteristics of a `inline-block` element, so the desired result might not be achieved.

Comment: @JoshC But IE7 is so weird that elements which are block by default with `display:inline` behave like `display:inline-block`

Comment: @JoshC I don't know, because I don't use hacks which aren't valid CSS. But if `*display` is a hack for IE7 (but not IE8), it should work well.